# reading data from a table edit and save in another table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

in my system i have read data from checkinout table(this table is created from a differenet system and i have to change some data for my system) edited those details and got the result list as List. Now i want to save those retrieved details in the record table.Can someone help me with this? Thx a lot.

records table(id,user_id,day,time)

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/records")
    public String read(Model model) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println("hey");
        List<CheckInOut> recordDetails= checkInOutDAO.findAll();
        //System.out.println(recordDetails.toString());

        CheckInOut[] arr = new CheckInOut[recordDetails.size()];
       for(int i = 0 ; i < recordDetails.size(); i++) {
            //System.out.println(recordDetails.get(i).getUserid());
            arr[i]=recordDetails.get(i);
        }

//result list
List<Records> recordsList= DateToDayConvert.main(arr);



        model.addAttribute("records",recordsList);
        return "records";
    }
```

DAO

```
 public Records save(Records records){
        return recordsRepository.save(records);
    }
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="records")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public class Records {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private int userid;
    private String day;
    private int time;


    public Records() {
    }

    public Records(int userid, String day, int time) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.day = day;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of call save for every record, you can save all records at a time.

### DOA

```
public Records save(Records records){
  return recordsRepository.save(records);
}

public List<Records> save(List<Records> records){
  return recordsRepository.save(records);
}
```

Now you can save all records in a single DB call.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding following code under result List. Thx evryone

```
(int i=0;i<recordsList.size();i++){      
     recordsDAO.save(recordsList.get(i));
}
```